# How to move and delete row properly in UITableView?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

In my use case cell is moved to indexPath 0-0 and then it's removed from the array. Both actions are wrapped in `beginUpdates()` `endUpdates()`. That causing problem with `willDisplay` and `didEndDisplaying`.
Some times `didEndDisplaying` not even called or `willDisplay` called two or more times, thats make my cell to be bounded multiple times.

Here is example project: https://github.com/mNijurin/table_playground
This project adds "1" on `willDisplay` and removes it on `didEndDisplaying` from the label in the cell. So in no cases we must see something like empty string or multiple "11".

When "do" button tapped, the program will move row 50 to indexPath 0-0 and remove it.

Scroll to 50 row and tap "do" all the cells on screen will be bounded twice. We can check it with labeles showing "11"

Here is the video: https://youtu.be/nCWkk2eLDWc

And here is the code:

```
var texts = [String]()    

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "do", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(doSome))

    navigationController?.navigationBar.isOpaque = true
    for i in 0...100 {
        texts.append("\(i)")
    }
}

@objc func doSome() {
    let text = texts[50]
    texts.remove(at: 50)
    texts.insert(text, at: 0)
    tableView.beginUpdates()
    tableView.moveRow(at: IndexPath(row: 50, section: 0), to: IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0))
    tableView.endUpdates()

    texts.remove(at: 0)
    tableView.beginUpdates()
    tableView.deleteRows(at: [IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)], with: .bottom)
    tableView.endUpdates()
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return texts.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if let someCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") {
        return someCell
    } else {
        let cell = UITableViewCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: "cell")
        let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 50, y: 0, width: 300, height: 40))
        label.textColor = .black
        label.tag = 13
        cell.textLabel?.addSubview(label)
        return cell
    }
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    print("bind row: \(indexPath.row) \(Unmanaged.passUnretained(cell).toOpaque())")
    cell.textLabel?.text = texts[indexPath.row]

    let label = cell.contentView.viewWithTag(13) as? UILabel
    label?.text = "\(label?.text ?? "")1"
    print("willDisplay \(label?.text ?? "")")
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didEndDisplaying cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    print("unbind row: \(indexPath.row) \(Unmanaged.passUnretained(cell).toOpaque())")
    cell.textLabel?.text = nil

    let label = cell.contentView.viewWithTag(13) as? UILabel
    if let text = label?.text, text.count == 1 {
        label?.text = ""
    } else if let text = label?.text, text.count > 0 {
        var text = text
        text.remove(at: text.index(text.endIndex, offsetBy: -1))
        label?.text = text
    }
    print("endDisplay \(label?.text ?? "")")
}
```

`

Comment: What is the version of Xcode?

Comment: xcode 9.3 ios 11

Comment: Don't (mis)use `willDisplay` and `didEndDisplaying`. Create a custom cell in Interface Builder and use an outlet for the label. Then delete both methods. And rather then `moveRow` use `deleteRows` and `insertRows` according to the `remove` / `insert` operation.

Comment: that worked, when table is not scrolling, but when scrolling down while last delete animation tries to scroll up I have one cell at the top for which  `willDisplay` was not called..

Answer (score -1):

To delete row from tableview

```
yourTableView.beginUpdates()
yourTableView.deleteRows(at: [IndexPath(row: yourModelArray.count - 1, section: 0)], with: .automatic)
yourTableView.endUpdates()
```